# How to split the substring without empty cells?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string, split

Example:

`"div#qwe.%class-first.class-two".split(/([#\.%])/)`

`["div", "#", "qwe", ".", "", "%", "class-first", ".", "class-two"]`

Cell 4 is empty. How do I get rid of this by using regex?

---

**UPD #1** I thought that `match` is slow, but it is not. My small test:

```
Match: 5
Filter: 15
Split: 11
Big match: 3092
Big filter: 7115
Big split: 2925
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `match`:

```
> "div#qwe.%class-first.class-two".match(/[#.%]|[^#.%]+/g)
["div", "#", "qwe", ".", "%", "class-first", ".", "class-two"]
```

You don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a single regex to be provided to `.split()`, given that your input data has two separators in a row, but other regex functions could do it or you can [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the result:

```
"div#qwe.%class-first.class-two".split(/([#\.%])/).filter(function(v){return v != "";})
```